# Does Auth Class require a DB?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

This may be simple but I just want to clarify something does the `Auth class` in Laravel requires a database to work? Cause I've been practicing user authentication without the database, just a simple string comparison .. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Laravel 4 Auth requires the use of a database.

There are two Auth drivers, one is called `database` and the other one, which is default, is called `eloquent` which also makes use of your database using Laravel's very own ORM layer.

Comment: so that means it won't work with simple string comparisons right?

Comment: right. not unless you create your own, database independent Auth driver.

Comment: well I'm only practicing using `Sessions` in Lavarel that's why I use the simple string comparison. Thanks!